# Is there a way to install the data directly at the installation of apk?

Tags: android

I use a TTS that requires a license and voice pack in the Android\data\voxygen.baradroid folder. 
This folder has several subfolders and files inside.

By adding the folder directly through a simple copy paste, everything works.
I can not find a way to install directly during the apk installation or to the first start of the application.

Is there a way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can put your file in resources/assets OR resources/raw and then when your app is launched for the first time you can access those files and create a copy at your specified location.

Following are the links to How to use assets in Android.

```
https://coderwall.com/p/0ldbgw/working-with-assets-in-android
https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xbifoj_x9W4
```